# How to force elements/tags like <i> and <b> to close within their parent element?

Tags: html

I'm going to allow users to submit HTML, strip the script and style tags (ofc), but certain elements, like Bold and Italic, are spilling out of the DIVision where the user content comes into. If they forget to close them I mean.

Example:

User submits:

```
I'm entering a <b>tunne----------------
```

The page ends up like this:

```
<div>
    I'm entering a <b>tunne----------------
</b><div><b> **rest of the page**
```

And thus the whole rest of the page turns **bold**. I'm confused by the behavior (why don't these things stay in their cages?). And I need a neat solution. I'd like there to be a cage tag, but there isn't. Using an iframe for this is extremely inappropriate.

Any ideas? I'd prefer to solve this without writing a parser to find unclosed tags.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately there's no way to force the browser to interpret unbalanced tags for you. Take this scenario:

```
<b>foo <i>bar</b> baz</i>
```

Should it leave the tags in place and render it as

**foo *bar*** baz

, or should the browser assume the `<i>` tag is the child and move its closing tag? Or maybe the user meant `<b>` is the child and to move its closing tag?

If you're going to allow user markup and you want to avoid rendering problems, then you can either count the total number of opening / closing tags to make sure they balance (and strip out all tags if they don't), or employ a more bulletproof service like Horen's answer above.

Also, its probably very unwise to allow users to submit HTML. Even if you blacklist certain tags, there's probably a whole bunch of [other exploits](http://www.technicalinfo.net/papers/CSS.html) left open. Much better to let users enter restricted Markdown or BBcode, then convert the characters you *do* allow into HTML.

Comment: Since those are both inline tags they should be allowed to interleave. But I'd like to have them stop at the block element surrounding them. I'd even be okay with having a special block element to contain them in.

Comment: Regarding it being unwise, that is probably true.

Comment: They are inline *by default*, but they can be set to block just as `<div>`s can be made inline with CSS. The point is that browsers don't know enough to make the decision, unfortunately!

Comment: The browser does really know if something is inline or not eventually. Anyway if block -> children must close inside. Or: if jail -> children must close inside.
Maybe it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a html sanitizer like [php tidy](https://www.php.net/tidy) which will clean and fix your source code.
Another option AFAIK would be [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/)

Comment: I don't actually use PHP, so this doesn't help me. I did mention I'd prefer not writing a parser, but using doesn't have my preference either.

Thanks anyway!

Comment: FYI: Tidy is a library written in C actually and there are many programming languages you can use it with